# Next js getServerSideProps redirect with props

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can I get the props after redirection?

```
return {
  redirect: {
    destination: '/auth-page',
    permanent: false,
  },
  props: {
    initialReduxState: {user},
  }
}
```

After the redirect, I am trying to get the props on the "auth-page". The props object is empty.

Comment: You won't have access to this page's props on the redirect destination. You can either pass query params through the URL to the destination page, or apply the same logic on the destination page to retrieve what you wanted to pass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would be grateful if you would give advice on how best to act in my situation.
In getServerSideProps I check the user's authorization. In case of a negative answer, I delete the user's data from the storage and redirect to "/ auth-page". After the redirect, I need to sync the store on the client. For synchronization, I need to accept parameters that contain initialReduxState.
It seems to me that it would be unreasonable to re-execute the authorization check logic on the "/ auth-page" page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually i have faced same problem with passing the props from page 1 SSR , to page 2 ,
i finally i found the the following solution by pass a query params   .

and here is the simple example :

- page1 : inside "server side props" function we will pass "force_logout" for example :

  ```
  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    return {
        redirect: {
          permanent: false,
          destination: "/users/login_page/?force_logout=true",
        },
      };
  }
  ```
- page2 : we will receive the query parameter inside "server side props"  and send it as props to the same page, as the following :

  ```
  const loginPage = (props) => {
    const {query} = props ?? null



    useEffect(() => {

   if(query?.force_logout === 'true'){
        console.log('yes force_logout is received ')
        const isServerSide = typeof window === "undefined";
        if(!isServerSide){
            localStorage.removeItem('test_key')
        }
       }


     }, [])




    return(
       <div> test login page </div>
      )
  }

  export default loginPage

  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const {query} = context
    console.log(query)
    return {
        props: {query}
    }
  }
  ```

this is just example , and change it based on you case/requirements .

i hope this helpful .